# If I make class level lock on static method & if one thread execute it so will it block other thread executing other instance method of same class?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Suppose we have one class in which we have one instance method and static method. We have synchronized block in static method with class level lock & we have synchronized block in instance method with object level lock. So suppose when one thread start executing static method and make class level lock , at the same time another thread try to execute instance method. So will that second thread will be blocked from execution of instance method ??

Comment: Is this one lock object, two lock objects or how is locked. Please read st [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second thread will not be blocked。the class level lock & this class Object level lock，the two locks are different, but they can be re-entered each other

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that both `static synchronized` and `non static synchronized` method can run `simultaneously` or `concurrently` because they lock on different object.

Comment: two non static synchronized method can also run simultaneously given the lock on two different object. Static synchronized means I am locking at class level e.g synchronized (A.class) .so at that time entire class get locked ?? so even other thread can not execute any instance method ??